# How to print stars pattern in from google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-console

```
for (int i = 5; i >= 1; i--)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");
```

That is the code I am trying to run.. but it is giving error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

How should I resolve it?

Comment: Um.. you are asking about javascript but posting what looks like Java (or C#) code...

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher you are totally right, Suraj P  Patil- do you mean JavaScript or C#??

Comment: This is C# code that you've posted. Are you trying to write it in JavaScript? Change `int` to `var` and change `Console.WriteLine` to `console.log`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have a strongly typed type system.

Drop the `int` from the for loop, replacing it with `var`:

`for (var i = 5; i >= 1; i--)`

and, once you've also substituted `Console.log` for `Console.WriteLine`, all will be well.

Comment: Why the downvote? The unexpected identifier is the type that the OP specified.

Comment: I had a mistake, which I've now corrected.

Comment: `Console.log` should not be capitalized, it should be `console.log` otherwise you will receive: `ReferenceError: Console is not defined`

Comment: After applying your suggestions it is giving one single star(*) output and saying "undefined"

Answer (score 1):

No need to declare the vartype in the for, simply use

```
for (i=5;i>=1;i--){ }
```

Try using

```
console.log();
```

Comment: You should use var in the declaration of `i` in the loop. But at least you caught the incorrect use of `console`

Comment: it is still giving error : Uncaught ReferenceError: Console is not defined at <anonymous>:5:12(anonymous function)

Comment: @SurajPPatil Because it's `console`, not `Console`. Javascript is case-sensitive.

Comment: After applying your suggestions it is giving one single star(*) output and saying "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Both of the other answers here neglect to include an important point. Indeed you should get rid of `int`, but it should be replaced with `var`, otherwise you are declaring global variables and populating the global scope with stuff it doesn't need. Generally bad practice.

For loops should look more like this:

```
for (var i=5;i>=1;i--){ }
```

Comment: it is still giving error  :
Uncaught ReferenceError: Console is not defined
 at <anonymous>:5:12(anonymous function)

Comment: `console.log`, not `Console.log`

Answer (score 0):

There is no a type declaration in JavaScript nor `Console.Write` or `Console.WriteLine`, it's not c#!

Change it to `console.log` and declare the variables with `var`:

```
for (var i = 5; i >= 1; i--)
     {
      for (var j = 0; j < i; j++)
          {
           Console.log("*");
          }
      Console.log();
     }
Console.log("---------------------------");
```

Comment: it is still giving error : Uncaught ReferenceError: Console is not defined at <anonymous>:5:12(anonymous function)